# Meteor Template onRendered callback not called

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, chartist.js

I am trying to use chartist.js with my meteor application. I placed the code for it in `Template.reportPage.onRendered()` so that it generate a bar chart after the template DOM have been inserted. I tried putting an alert in and see that it's never called. I also have a helper define in `Template.reportPage.helpers` and it runs fine.

I'm getting the error:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Template.reportPage.onRendered')
    (anonymous function)
```

Here is my code:

```
Template.reportPage.onRendered(function(){
    var data = {};
    var orders = Orders.find({
        created_at: {
            //query for month 3
            $gt: new Date(2015, 2, 0),
            $lte: new Date(2015, 3, 0)
        }
    }, {sort: {created_at: 1}} ).fetch(); //ascending

    data.series = [[]];

    var noOfDays = new Date(2015,3,0).getDate()

    data.labels = _(noOfDays).times( function(n) {
        data.series[0][n] = 0;
        return n+1;
    });

    orders.forEach(function(order, index, array){
        var date = order.created_at.getDate();
        data.series[0][date-1]++;
    });
    console.log(data);
    alert('comon');
    new Chartist.Bar('#orderVsTime', data); //put chart in element with #orderVsTime

 });
```

Comment: wich meteor version are you using?

Comment: @Ethaan, I did meteor update and it works now, but the Orders.find() in onRendered gives me an empty array, but if I do it in the console afterward, I get something.

Comment: copy/paste that query on the console and tell me what you get.

Comment: @Ethaan I got an array of 9 objects, seem as if minimongo is not ready?

Comment: Yep, with the new version of meteor there is a subscription method, use it on this rendered to know when the subscription is ready

Comment: @Ethaan thanks a lot, works now. I had to put the query and other code inside onReady callback of the subscribe method which I called in the onRendered method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onRendered method is newly added as of meteor version 1.0.4. Are you sure your app's version is 1.0.4? If not, try updating via `meteor update`. If you do not want to update you can try the deprecated version:

```
Template.reportPage.rendered = function () {
  // your code 
}
```